# Sharepoint Site Administration

Tags: sharepoint, iis, administration

I've got a SharePoint website running on my machine (which it shows me inside the Application Pool in the Inet Manager).

Now this website has a different user credentials specified under the Identity section (properties). Also when I view the w3wp.exe in the task manager it shows that the site is running as a different user.

The problem is that if I change the username and password of the existing user with mine, the site stops working.
How do I run it under my account credentials.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Stops working? I would be helpful if you could provide a little more information than that. Error message etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the account that runs the SharePoint application pool, you must make sure that the new account has the same permissions as the current one. That includes the correct database permissions. Otherwise the SharePoint Web Application stops working.

The behavior you are describing is normal. Whatever account you use to login to your SharePoint site, the application pool will still be using the account assigned to it.

Regards,
M